# Type mismatch does NOT create error during "compilation" time

Tags: typescript, typegraphql

I would like to understand way there are no errors in this resolver even where there is a type mismatch.

I am saying that the `Query` should return an `Int` but it actually returns a `String`.
If I execute it, it **does** complain. But is there a way to have the error at "compilation" time? Without me having to execute the query in the playground in order to see if there is a type error?

```
import { Int, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";

@Resolver()
export class MyResolver {
  @Query(() => Int)
  hello() {
    return "hello"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible right now for decorators to annotate the type of a function. You can explicitly type the function's return:

```
import { Int, Query, Resolver } from "type-graphql";

@Resolver()
export class MyResolver {
  @Query(() => Int)
  hello(): number {
    return "hello" // error
  }
}
```

Sadly there is duplication here, but it's the best you can get.

If you want you could also make a type that gets the correct type from the GraphQL type:

```
GetType<Int>; // number
GetType<[Int]>; // number[]
// etc
```

EDIT: [Took some time to make the type myself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)